# Use Gson parse following string

Tags: java, android, gson

I use Gson to parse flowing string,but I get an exeption.Here is my string data:

```
[
  {
    "source": "Gank.io #145 (2015-12-24)",
    "title": "view",
    "url": "https://github.com/florent37/ViewAnimator"
  },
  {
    "source": "Gank.io #42 (2015-07-23)",
    "title": "android",
    "url": "https://github.com/kevinzhow/NaughtyImageView"
  },
  {
    "source": "Gank.io #28 (2015-07-02)",
    "title": "iOS UIView",
    "url": "http://www.devtalking.com/articles/uiview-spring-animation/"
  }

]
```

I use flowing code to parse above string:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
SearchResultData searchResultData = gson.fromJson(json,SearchResultData.class);
List<SearchResult> searchResults = searchResultData.getResults();
```

My exception is :

```
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Comment: post `SearchResultData` here.

Comment: `public class SearchResultData {
    private List<SearchResult> results;

    public List<SearchResult> getResults() {
        return results;
    }


    public void setResults(List<SearchResult> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, hope it helps!

```
class SearchResultData {
    String source;
    String title;
    String url;
}

...

private final List<SearchResultData> dataList= new ArrayList<>();
...
Gson gson = new Gson();
SearchResultData[] data= gson.fromJson(jsonString, SearchResultData[].class);
Collections.addAll(dataList, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

SearchResultData should contain a field of type Array or List to parse it normally.

Another suggestion - do it in such way:

```
List<SearchResultEntry> searchResultData = gson.fromJson(json,SearchResultEntry.class);
```

where SearchResultEntry is a POJO-class containing source, title and url Strings.

The error

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

Tells you that SearchResultData expecting object as

```
{
    "source": "Gank.io #145 (2015-12-24)",
    "title": "view",
    "url": "https://github.com/florent37/ViewAnimator"
}
```

but Gson found  an array of such objects.

**According to your clarification, this is the right JSON structure:**

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
        "source": "Gank.io #145 (2015-12-24)",
        "title": "view",
        "url": "https://github.com/florent37/ViewAnimator"
      },
      {
        "source": "Gank.io #42 (2015-07-23)",
        "title": "android",
        "url": "https://github.com/kevinzhow/NaughtyImageView"
      },
      {
        "source": "Gank.io #28 (2015-07-02)",
        "title": "iOS UIView",
        "url": "http://www.devtalking.com/articles/uiview-spring-animation/"
      }

    ]
}
```

Comment: You're right,but I decide to use the above answer .Thanks